# pdf.js not working anymore in any browser, not even the examples

Tags: pdf.js

Today suddenly PDFJS didn't work anymore. Strange enough I can't find a lot of other users facing this problem except one: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9526

Do you see the same errors in their own examples?
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred after this update: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/commit/b8606abbc1448ffd26ad553b253e2fb72d7f2cb7

It wasn't backward compatible, not even the examples.

The solution is to replace PDFJS with pdfjsDistBuildPdf.
So:

```
pdfjsDistBuildPdf.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

and

```
pdfjsDistBuildPdf.getDocument({data: pdfData});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I solved the problem by adding the following line at the top of my script:

```
var PDFJS = pdfjsLib;
```

Hope this helps